# apache crontab not executing

Tags: linux, fedora, cron

I use cron to execute some php scripts (owncloud background tasks etc). My server runs nginx and PHP via php-fpm, which by default runs PHP processes under the `apache` user, the only user with write access to `/var/www` aside from root. Thus it should be fine to add these background jobs to apache`s crontab:

```
crontab -u apache -e
```

The contents:

```
MAILTO=cron@localhost
*  *  *  *  * echo "..." | mail -s "crontest" cron@localhost
```

This should send me a mail every minute, however it does not. When I run the command as the apache user (`sudo -s -u apache`), it works fine, but the cronjob never executes.

I found some mention of "locked accounts" [here](http://www.lazysystemadmin.com/2010/09/enable-cron-for-locked-account-in-linux.html), but I'm not sure if the suggested solution is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, `/var/log/cron` gave me a clue.

```
CROND[7709]: (apache) CMD (echo "..." | mail -s "crontest" cron@localhost)
CROND[7709]: (CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/usr/share/httpd): No such file or directory
```

The issue is that cron tries to [switch to the user's home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/417850/why-isnt-my-cronjob-running#comment444230_418268) before executing anything. However, as I didn't have apache installed, /usr/share/httpd didn't exist. I guess creating that directory would work, but using sudo as root should be the better solution here.

```
* * * * * sudo -u apache env TERM=xterm php -f /var/www/owncloud/cron.php
```

`env TERM=xterm` avoids a warning from cron.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the number 60 is valid in the minutes column (someone correct me if I'm wrong). The number should be between 0 and 59.

What you're actually telling the machine to do is "run `echo "..." | mail -s "crontest" cron@localhost` every 60 minutes". If you want the job to run every minute, the line would be:

`*/1 *  *  *  * echo "..." | mail -s "crontest" cron@localhost`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: You are right, the syntax is incorrect. But I put that in there just for testing, now with a valid syntax it doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe it's a `$PATH` issue? Try specifying the full path to `mail` and `echo` in the crontab entry.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I've worked around it (see my answer).